# Парсер tiobe.com с добавлением в свой проект

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Я создаю свой первый учебный проект в **Django**. Он связан с классификацией и описанием языков программирования. У меня возник вопрос, возможно ли с сайта [tiobe.com](https://www.tiobe.com/tiobe-index/) спарсить таблицу с топ-20 языков и диаграмму рейтинга и добавить к себе на сайт, чтобы данные обновлялись автоматически? В какую сторону хотя бы смотреть, для реализации такого?

Comment: Как вариант вы можете с помощью bs4 спарсить таблицу, после сформировать с этих данных список, и при помощи jinja в цикле выводить эту таблицу на сайт

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, кому-то пригодится в будущем.
Я не стала парсить ничего, а воспользовалась тегами `<iframe></iframe>`.
В моем шаблоне это выглядит так:

```
{% extends 'programmingLanguages/base.html' %}
{% block content %}

<style>
.iframe_block {
overflow: hidden;
width: 100%; /* Ширина окна */
height: 2200px; /* Высота окна */
}

.iframe_class {
border: 10px;
margin-left: -20px; /* Положение по горизонтали */
margin-top: -680px; /* Положение по вертикали */
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
</style>

    <div class= "card border-dark" style="padding: 10px; margin-block-end: 10px">
        <div class="card-header border-danger">
            <h1>{{title}}</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body" style="background-color: #e8eef4; height: 1600px">
            <div class="iframe_block">
                <!--noindex--><iframe sandbox="allow-scripts" class="iframe_class" loading = "lazy" src="https://www.tiobe.com/tiobe-index/"  scrolling="no">
                Ваш браузер не поддерживает iframe!
                </iframe><!--/noindex-->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

Подробнее можно почитать тут [>>>](https://www.pandoge.com/stati-i-sovety/kak-pokazat-tolko-opredelennuyu-oblast-element-v-iframe)